# Rectangle in a triangle

Tags: c++, math, graphics, 3d

I am trying to build a program in C++ that will procedurally generate cities. 
For the moment, the city is represented by an array of blocks either Quad blocks or Triangle blocks.

I can't find an effective way to subdivide a triangle (TBlock) into a rectangle (QBlock) and three triangles.

[image]

So picture a triangle ABC. We have two point T and T' which are the first and second tier of line segment BC. 
Now I need to find P and P' which are respectively on AB and AC line segments. 
P is the intersection of AB and the normal of BC passing through T. 
P' is the intersection of AB and the normal of BC passing through T'.

I know how to find T and T' and the inward normal of vector BC but I can't find a way to compute the normal passing through T or T'.

Thanks !

Comment: upload an image somewhere else and ask for someone to add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks OlayinkaSF. If anyone can edit my post to add the following image, thanks a lot : http://imgur.com/nYOTwWB

Answer (score 1):

Given your (BC) vector is (x, y), a normal vector of BC is (-y, x). Now offset the normal  vector by coordinates of T', and you will get the normal of BC passing through T'.

Answer (score 1):

the normal to a line `y = m*x + c` is the line `y = (-1/m)*x + d`, where `c`  and  `d` are constants.
You have two lines with a common point (T or T'), you can solve simultaneously to find `m` and  `d` for both T and T'.

Comment: Thanks OlayinkaSF. Unfortunately I wasn't asking the right question. See my precedent comment.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the angle formed by CBA is the same angle formed by TBP. Let's call that O.  You also know the distance between B and T.  Call it D.  Using this we can find P using trigonometry.

Tan(O) = X / D

Where X is the y_axis distance between T and P. Just solve for X since you know O and D.

Once you know X you can just add X to the y value of T to find P.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers. I can't upvote yet but I will do when I can..
I'd like to update my question after testing some of your stuff. It seems that I can't use the algorithm I made up for every kind of triangle. So does anyone know how to find the biggest rectangle inscribed in a triangle ?
Do I have to update my original question or is it best to post a new one ?

Comment: @SilouaneGerin I advise you go to [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com), this is a geometry problem and you will get better help there